# Topology of $GL_n(K)$

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, vector-bundles

I need to show any of the following results:

Consider $K=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, then,

1) The compact-open topology and the usual topology of $GL_n(K)$ are the same.

2) Taking inverses and multiplication are continuous in $GL_n(K)$ with the compact-open topology.

or

3) Give the bijection between $(X\times K^n)^{K^n}$ and $X^{GL_n(K)}$ and show that $\alpha\in (X\times K^n)^{K^n}$ is continuous iff $\hat{\alpha}\in  X^{GL_n(K)}$  is continuous, where $\hat{\alpha}$ is its associated function.

I need any of these results in order to prove that a morphism of vector bundles is an isomorphism when it is a linear isomorphism in each fiber. I think proving 1) would be the best, but at this point any of the other results will do.

I'm completely stuck with it, so I would really appreciate any kind of help that can get me on track.

Answer (score 1):

Since $K^n$ is a metric space, the compact-open topology coincides with the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of the domain; also, since the topology of $K^n$ has a countable basis and it is $\sigma$-compact, the compact-open topology itself has a countable basis, and it is therefore determined by its convergent sequences. You can check at once that a sequence of linear maps converges uniformly on all compact sets iff it converges uniformly on the unit ball, and more or less by definition a sequence of linear maps converges uniformly on the unit ball iff it converges in the topology given by norm of $\hom(K^n,K^n)$. This last topology is the «usual» topology you refer to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mariano. Unfortunately I can't follow the proof as I'd like. Please tell me if I'm right:

Comment: 1) The compact-open topology is countable since $\{(K,U)\}$ with $K$ compact and $U$ open is countable.
2) Could you please provide me a reference in which they show how to construct a topology from its convergent sequences?
3) I assume the unit ball convergence follows from the linearity of the functions?

Comment: 1) There are uncountably many pairs $(K,U)$, simply because there are uncountably many open sets, for example. I suggest you read the section on the compact-open topology on some good general topology textbook. 2) That a topology with a countable basis is determined by its convergent sequences should be explained in most textbooks dealing wth countabe bases. 3) Try to prove it.